# Fractions+Symbols+Python3

Tags: python-3.x, symbols

I want to write code in Python3, which deals with fractions and symbols.

The code shall take in 2 fractions with symbols, do some basic arithmetics(+ and *), and deliver a fraction with symbols. Here an example:

(3x/10) + (2y/20) = (3x+y)/10

I could get the fractions work with `import fractions` and the symbols with `import sympy` but I couldn't get them work together. Neither did I find out how to do it purely in sympy.

Greetings, 
JP

Comment: why do you need fractions with sympy - won't it keep exact representations by default?  Or do you want symbolic equations without simplification from sympy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`sympy`](http://www.sympy.org) uses fractions ( called [`Rational`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=rational#sympy.core.numbers.Rational)s in sympy) automatically:

```
from sympy import symbols, srepr

x, y = symbols('x y')

expr = (3*x/10) + (2*y/20) + (3*x+y)/10

print(expr)         # 3*x/5 + y/5
print(srepr(expr))  # Add(Mul(Rational(3, 5), Symbol('x')),
                    #     Mul(Rational(1, 5), Symbol('y')))
```

if it did not, `3*x/5` would evaluate as `0.6*x`.

Comment: simple is best. thank you very much!  i was thinking in a totally wrong and complicated direction

Comment: sorry, can't upvote yet.  this was my first question :/ but you clearly deserve an upvote